# Update google calendar description javascript

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

Im working on an application for google calendar. I can get calendars, create events and display them but i cannot seem to update a specific calendars metadata.

I have this function

```
function setCalendarDescription(calendarId) {

var send ={
    "resource" :{
    "description" : "test"
    }
};
console.log(send);
var request = gapi.client.calendar.calendars.update({
    'calendarId': calendarId,
    'resource': send

});
console.log(request);
request.execute(function(resp) {
    alert("updated description in calendar");
});
}
```

And im calling it in this function

```
function listCalendars() {
var request = gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list();

request.execute(function(resp) {
    var calendars = resp.items;
    var counter = 0;
    //console.log(calendars);
    for (i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {

        var calendar = resp.items[i];
        var calId = calendar.id;
        var calName = calendar.summary;
        var accessRole = calendar.accessRole;
        if (accessRole == "owner") {

            var ulEvents = document.getElementById("events");
            var nH3 = document.createElement('ul');
            var nH3Text = document.createTextNode("Upcoming events for calendar " + calName + ":");
            nH3.appendChild(nH3Text);
            nH3.setAttribute("id", "upcoming" + i);
            ulEvents.appendChild(nH3);
            listUpcomingEvents(calId, counter);
            calendarArray[counter] = calendar;
            setCalendarDescription(calId);
            counter++;
        }

    }

});
}
```

I have looked [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/) for a solution and the web but have yet to find one.

If anyone has some directions i'd appreciate it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not look thoroughly enough the documentation and the answer was right there. 
It's not enough to only supply a description for the calendar, you need to supply

```
description     string  Description of the calendar.
location        string  Geographic location of the calendar as free-form text. 
summary         string  Title of the calendar.
timeZone        string  The time zone of the calendar.
```